# What it means to name path

Tags: paths

My teacher has given me example code be he says be sure to name the path i am confused what he means by this

example code:

```latex
% Plot 1st data from file (you don't even have to open the files)
% Make sure to name the path!
\addplot+ [smooth,mark=none,name path=boundary1] table [x=Extensometer, y=Load, col sep=comma] {Data/ExampleDataSteel1.csv};
```

Comment: Where is the CSV file in relation to the TEX file where you have this code? Here the CSV is in a subfolder names `Data`

Comment: the path name (a name given to the graph) is the option `name path=boundary1` in your line. That name is probably used in the rest of the code to identify that specific graph for further processing (adding labels, finding intersection, shading regions...). Impossible to know with just this line of code....and by the way, welcome to TeX.SX!